# Sqlite. Numbers sorting

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have Sqlite Database;

```
-- Описать CITY
CREATE TABLE City (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, region_id NUMERIC, name TEXT, population NUMERIC, aver_salary NUMERIC, unemployment NUMERIC, education NUMERIC, wealth NUMERIC)
```

The aver_salary, unemployment, education and wealth store values like:
15,65 or 9,0 or 10,09.

I put all data with Java. In java I work with strings only.

The problem is when I try to sort like this:

```
SELECT * FROM City ORDERY BY aver_salary DESC
```

the 12,00 value comes before 111,00. So it compares strings not values.

Am I Correct that I should change Java data types to double to correctly sort those values in sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well all in all problem is solved.

What I did is:
1. Changed NUMERIC to REAL in SQLite
2. Changed String to Double in Java.

Everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The sort (ORDER BY) is in SQLite, not Java. So it should sort numerically.

It will only sort "wrong" if you then sort in Java *afterwards*. So I guess that, yes, use Double not String for these values in Java because they are numbers. But you should remove the Java sort too.

Comment: I do not sort in Java. I browse data in Sqlite browser. SQkit sorts aver_salary like string not like double->this is the problem.